# Porting a C++ library - openSMILE to Android

Tags: android, speech, emotion

I want guidance on how to port the opensource openSMILE http://opensmile.sourceforge.net/ library which is in C++ to Android. Specifically how should I use SWIG to create the caller code in JAVA and how should I use the Android-NDK to create the JNI in my android app? I have absolutely no experience with Android programming so I am not sure of how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Please see Version 2.3. of openSMILE from http://opensmile.audeering.com/.

It contains an Android Studio example project with JNI interface and build scripts to compile library and binary for Android with NDK.

Answer (score 0):

```
 how to port the opensource openSMILE.?
```

You can download whole source code of that library and then cross compile it for your platform then install it in android stack or use it in jni

```
 Specifically how should I use SWIG to create the caller code in JAVA..?
```

Here you need to write wrapper for each API of that library in jni c then you will have java exported API of that library which you can use in your android application.

Comment: Can the wrappers be directly generated by SWIG? if so how? Or is it necessary to write each wrapper manually?

Comment: i dont think you can generate wrappers automatically you need to write each wrapper manually. For that you need to studu JNI in depth